# pyspark: how to use filter function to compare a rdd with a list

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

So i have a list

```
list = [11, 5, 7, 2, 18]
```

and a RDD of a list

```
RDD = sc.parallelize([5, 4, 3, 2, 6])
```

and I want to the filter function on RDD to return every element, when summed with the corresponding element in list, has a sum less than or equals to 10. So in this example, I want it to return an RDD with the elements 4, 3, 2. How do I do this?

Edit: So I've tried turning RDD into a key value pair where the key is the index, then I do this

```
def compare(x, list_):
    i = x[0]
    if x[1] + list_[i]) <= 10:
        return x
    
rdd_new = rdd.filter(compare)
```

but it doesnt seem to work as when I do `rdd_new.collect()` I get a bunch of errors

Comment: can you post what you have tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: I have edited above